# How to make GQL query payload from interface or type?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

Let's say that I have a query like this.

```
`query SampleQuery($arg1: String, $arg2: String) {
sampleSearch(arg1: $arg1, arg2: $arg2) {
    sampleResponse {
        field1,
        field2,
        field3,
        nestedField1{
            fieldA
        }

    }
}}`;
```

And I have an Interface that has the same fields as this query's response. And I want to simplify this query to something like this so that I don't have to write redundant fields again and again.

```
`query SampleQuery($arg1: String, $arg2: String) {
    sampleSearch(arg1: $arg1, arg2: $arg2) {
        sampleResponse {
            ...MySampleInterface

        }
    }
}`;
```

I tried converting Interface fields to a string but it is not possible if I don't initialize the values to something. Is there a way/work-around available to achieve simplicity in GQL query writing?